# Order of evaluation

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I wonder if construction like this (initialization list) has well defined EO (evaluation order):

```
struct MemoryManager
    {
        Pair* firstPair_;//<-beg
        Pair* currentPair_;
        Pair* lastPair_;//<-end

        MemoryManager():lastPair_(currentPair_ = firstPair_ = nullptr)
            {/*e.b.*/}
};
```

If yes I personally would prefer this way to the more conventional:

```
    MemoryManager():firstPair_(nullptr),
                    currentPair_(nullptr),
                    lastPair_(nullptr)
    {/*e.b*/}
```

Comment: That's a genius idea, chaining the operator= like that. I never thought of that.

Comment: @DeadMG so tell me my man, is the effect of my "doing" the same to the traditional way? For I got two answers and both are different and doesn't really answer to my Q.

Comment: If you have to ask if it works it is not going to be clear to anyone else reading your code either. this is not genius but madness

Comment: @There: I don't really know. I don't like the initialization list order at all- I think they should be initialized in the order you initialize them. I've never developed a class where it mattered.

Comment: @jk I'm asking because I'm not proficient in C++ and I do not know well enough rules of evaluation. For professional it should be obvious. Would you also say that this is hard to read to someone who is proficient with C++: a = b = c; and you would rather type b = c; a = b;? And are you also typing int a; and in next line a = /*some value*/;?

Comment: but you already answer your own question by pointing out the 'more conventional' way, proficient C++ users would rather see the conventional way

Comment: perhaps you need to address what you don't like about the conventional way?

Comment: @jk I don't like about the conventional way (yes in school they thought me to answer with full sentence ;) the fact that I have to say three times the same thing where in fact I need to say it just once: All my pointers are equal nullptr, instead of (more traditionally: this pointer equals nullptr, the other pointer equals nullptr and that last one pointer also equals nullptr). That I do not like about the conventional way.

Comment: @DeadMG thanks for your answer. At least someone not affraid to say I just don't know. Respect;

Comment: Wow, this is funky.  Very brittle, hard to understand, easy to break.  I'm a professional with almost 20 years C++ experience, and I have to sit here and *think* about this construct.  Imagine what a newbie maintennence programmer would do with it.  Sorry, @There is nothing, regardless of the correctness of this construct, I think it's pretty bad.

Comment: @John how on earth someone with almost 20y of C++'ing can have any problems with a = b = c? Can you explain that to me? And can you also explain what is it so more brittle and easier to break about my construct compared to "the traditional way"? I'm really looking to your answer to both of my questions, preferably with some supporting examples.

Comment: @There:  `currentPair_ = firstPair_ = nullptr` isn't hard to understand, that's not the issue.  The issue is whether or not they have even been constructed yet.  It turns out they have, because primitive members are constructed in the order in which they are declared.  It's brittle because if you change the order of declaration, the construct may break.  It's hard to understand because in order to know if it's correct or not you need to know the order of declaration.  The traditional way is less brittle because even if you change the order of initialization or the order of...

Comment: ...declaration, the initialization is still done in the correct order.  The compiler will re-order your initializations to match the declarations.  Moreover, a construct which depends on a specific order of initialization is itself inheritly brittle.

Comment: @John anyway having said what I've said just thought of some real world example, the Bjarne's way:while (*destination++ = *source++); When you see code like this are you also puzzled for half a day trying to solve the mistery? I'm sorry but that's exactly what Bjarne says about C++ - constructs like this makes people either love or hate this language. I'm in total love. And I don't really care about your opinion on this subject because I know that my way is the C++ way. And I'm sorry but since when are real world programs written with the purpose to be understand by newbies?

Comment: @There:  Again, the problem isn't with the multiple initialization.  The problem is with it happening in a constructor initialization list.  But, whatever.  If you're going to be a jerk about it, ("I don't really care about your opinion") then I'll do you the favor of never answering any of your posts again.  It's a little ironic that  you say that you're "not proficient in C++," but when you get some criticism from someone who's been around the block a couple times, your respond with vitriol.  Good luck regardless.

Comment: @John Do not take my words out of a context. I didn't say: "I don't really care about your opinion". What I've said is: "I don't really care about your opinion on this subject" - it does sound little bit different does it? And it's not me who is actually touchy, it's you my man. And feel free not to answer anymore to any of my Q's. Good luck to you.

Comment: Does not matter if it works or not. In terms of maintenance it is a pain. The first maintainer to come along will spend two days trying to work out what you are doing then change the code to something that other people will understand. This would never pass code review in any company I have worked for because it is not intuitive and the alternative (though longer answer) is easy to understand. Easy to understand **ALWAYS** beats stupid clever tricks.

Comment: @There is nothing: a bit different, yes, but not much. If you don't care about his opinion *here*, why should he assume you'll care about it anywhere else? And then, why take the trouble of giving you his opinion on any other question? I don't think he's *that* desperate for your approval. What a pity you had to follow up an interesting question with such childish and petty comments.

Comment: "I have to say three times the same thing where in fact I need to say it just once": I'm not sure I follow. Is it more intuitive to say "set x to null and set y to x and set z to y" than it is to say "set x to null, set y to null, set z to null"? You're still making three statements.

Comment: @There: John's got experience, you should take his advice. We've all been in the "Anyone can understand this piece of code with half a brain!"-stage. The thing is that even the most experienced developer can have a hard day. A day when a thousand things needs to be done, preferably yesterday. It is during those periods when things like this become the weak link - you do a seemingly harmless change, and *bam* it all goes up in smoke. I have almost 17 years of experience in C++, and many of those years have been spent learning how to not trick myself a busy day in the future...

Comment: @jalf to your last comment - I don't say "set x to null and set y to x and set z to y" - that's only the result of what I'm saying. What I actually say is this: set x, y and z to nullptr;

Comment: @John Dibling ok, I think I was bit too harsh and I shouldn't say that I don't care - for that - I'm sorry.

Comment: @There I can understand not liking elements of C++ syntax, but really you are better off not fighting the syntax, C++ just doesn't have a way to say set x, y znd z to null

Comment: @jk but I'm not fighing the syntax - I do use legal and valid syntax of C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. As shown in your code, the members will be initialized in the same order they are *declared in the struct/class definition* (the order of initializers in the constructor definition is irrelevant, at best you will get a warning telling you they are in an incorrect order).

> 12.6.2 §5: Then, nonstatic data members shall be initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).

<strike>Note that this is only true for variables that are part of the same access specifier, so for instance variables found in a `public:` specifier may be initialized before or after those found in a `private:` specifier (the `struct` counts as a `public:` specifier, of course).</strike>

EDIT: the above paragraph was incorrect, I was thinking of allocation, not initialization:

> 9.2 §12: Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class declared without an intervening access-specifier are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of nonstatic data members separated by an access-specifier is unspecified (class.access.spec).

However, the more conventional way has a reason to exist, namely that if the order of declaration of the variables changes (for instance, due to refactoring), the code will not break silently. People don't readily assume the order of declaration is relevant, unless a warning tells them otherwise.

Comment: The last part sounds surprising to me; so we have defined order of initialization for members in one "access-specifier part" but undefined between those? Do several separate `public:` parts count as one? How does that relate to the rule that the member destructors must be called in the reverse order of construction (which is the main rationale behind having a strict rule behind order of construction?)

Comment: @Victor but if you say that the order of evaluation has a well defined order so by saying "... the more conventional way has a reason to exist..." you are contradicting yourself. Why? Because if the order of evaluation has well defined order both ways are equivalent.

Comment: @There is nothing: this is no contradiction. There is more to a piece of code than whether it works or not: ease of maintenance is also an essential factor, and while both approaches *do the same thing*, the conventional way makes code easier to maintain because it's harder for a small near-unrelated change to break its behavior.

Comment: @Victor could you please elaborate on this (your last comment)? If you're saying that: Order of evaluation is well defined it doesn't matter if I use the conventional way or not - the effect is the same. And I will say more - if a small near-unrelated change will break using first method it will break in the second method too. And could you please answer to Kos question?

Comment: @There is nothing: with the conventional method, a warning would be issued on most compilers because the order of the initializer list would not match the actual order anymore. The programmer could then notice the break at compile time, instead of two months later on a tech support call.

Comment: @Victor but (and I have to repeat myself) if those two methods are == the warning message would be issued in both cases, wouldn't it? For I first initialize firstP_ then currentP_ and at the end lastP_. Just like with the traditional approach but in one line instead of three.

Comment: @There is nothing: by definition the warning is issued when **two** initializers in the initializer list are in the wrong order. Your alternative solution contains **one** initializer, so there's no possible way for the warning to be issued.

Comment: @Victor let's leave the warnings for a moment, could you please answer if (my_way == traditional_way)?

Comment: @There is nothing: Yes, it is.

Comment: @Victor: As the members are POD, they will not be default initialized and so unless the OP added an explicit (out of order) initialization then the order of declaration in the class is irrelevant for this example.

Comment: @There is nothing: Wow, that's not a good way to discuss an answer. It's equal in that it accomplishes the same thing, but it's also worse. Don't you understand that? Why even ask the question then?

Answer (score 4):

As John Dibling has remarked, your construct is technically correct for the given concrete example, but it's brittle and it's hard to understand for many programmers.

Brittleness:

- Can fail if order of declaration is changed.
- Can fail if the init list is changed.

To evaluate such constructs on your own, keep this idea foremost in your mind: code is not about instructing the compiler to do your bidding, it is about communicating your intent to others (and perhaps your later self).

Hence, try to write *clear* code.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: thank you for your answer. Although I do agree with you that code should be written in a "clear" manner I also believe that in order to read any real world code, one has to know peculiarities of a specific language. And C++ has those "quirks" which as I've said before either makes people love it or hate it. As for brittlenes? Well, if in "traditional approach" you will order of your members in a class and you wont change the order in a ctor init list the code can also fail so I really do not see any (and I really mean it) benefits of listing every member separately.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: your comment does not make sense. perhaps you haven't understood that the declaration order completely determines initialization order? Anyway, what's with all this Abba stuff?

Comment: I'm recently (last few years) fascinated by Alan Partrige's character. It's genius.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, then do it the way everybody understands immediately without having to browse the standard:

```
MemoryManager()
  // no initialization here
{
  lastPair_ = currentPair_ = firstPair_ = nullptr;
}
```

However, I don't really see what this buys you over

```
MemoryManager()
  : lastPair_(), currentPair_(), firstPair_()
{}
```

which does exactly the same in only about half a dozen more characters.

Comment: and second_ = first_ and last_ = second_. No need to look in the std. It's obvious. Now, I've mentioned this construct: while (*destination++ = *source++); and I'm sure that when people saw this for a first time in their lives (even experienced guys) they had to spend some time to figure out what's going on. But after get use to see constructs like the one I've just mentioned they don't see it as a something uninteligible and hard to "swallow". On the contrary - they use it themselfs. And why they use it - because it says in most direct and tearse way what it does.And my construct is the same:

Comment: It says what it does in most direct and tearse way - the C++ way.

Comment: @sbi just've made another observation which is: you're saying that: "does exactly the same in only about half a dozen more characters". Well, to be precise in 8 more, but this is only when you have 3 pointers to play with. Try to do it with 10 pointers for example and you will be shocked how many more characters you have to type compared to my method.

Comment: @There: "From your solution it is absolutely not obvious from the first look to what are those pointers initialized." Well, anyone knowing the basics of C++ should know that `ptr()` will default-initialize `ptr`.

Comment: "`second_ = first_ and last_ = second_`. No need to look in the std." See, this is what my first example does. (And, yes, everyone familiar with the basics of C++ should know that PODs not mentioned in the initialization list aren#t initialized at all.) The way _you_ did it, however, required everyone to refer to the standard and made the first two people answering giving opposite advice.

Comment: "Well, to be precise in 8 more [...]. Try to do it with 10 pointers" So what? __A line of code is written once, but read dozens, hundreds, or thousands of times.__ So the time it takes to type it is irrelevant, what matters is only how long it takes to read and understand it. And people have been telling you that it is very hard to tell what it does. __If you don't want to listen what people tell you, why do you come here to ask them?__

Comment: @sbi no need to get agitated. Just because some people have problem with understanding what someone somewhere wrote, doesn't necessary mean that what this person wrote is bad. I will use this: while(*dest++ = *source++) as an example. How many people do you think had to spend more then few minutes to decifer what it means and what it does and why? And yet people love it. You know why - because: It says what it does in most direct and tearse way - the C++ way.

Comment: @sbi and it isn't like I don't want to listen what people tell me. But sometimes I just know what's best for me.

Comment: @There: Well, _you_ came here and asked a question. Why did you do this when you know what's best for you despite what others say? (And anyway, how does that matter when you write code that's to be maintained by others?) And it's not just been "some people" you have been banging your head against, it's top SO C++ answerers. You have several `c++` gold batches against you. But don't worry, just go ahead. May those coming after you curse you. I just wish SO supported plonking. You aren't open to reasoning anyway.

Comment: @sbi I came here and ask this question to make sure that order of eval. of this expression is well defined. That's it. I didn't ask if someone like it or not. And I am open to reasoning but this case is closed for me. More than sure that some people liked it and they will use it in their code, so don't be surprised when you see this construct at some point ;).

Answer (score 0):

For this specific example, the initialization order for members is irrelevant.  The following constructor would have the same behaviour as the one in the question:

```
MemoryManager():firstPair_(lastPair_ = currentPair_ = nullptr)
{/*e.b.*/}
```

This is because the members are [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) and so are not default initialized by the constructor at all (12.6.2/4 C++ '03):

> If a given nonstatic data member or base class is not named by a mem-initializer-id (including the case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor has no ctor-initializer), then
>
> - If the entity is a nonstatic data member of (possibly cv-qualified) class type (or array thereof) or a base class, and the entity class is a non-POD class, the entity is default-initialized (8.5). If the entity is a non- static data member of a const-qualified type, the entity class shall have a user-declared default constructor.
> - Otherwise, the entity is not initialized. If the entity is of const-qualified type or reference type, or of a (possibly cv-qualified) POD class type (or array thereof) containing (directly or indirectly) a member of a const-qualified type, the program is ill-formed.

For the raw pointer members above, the 'otherwise' bullet applies.

Now, even if the members did have class type, say:

```
class MbrType {
public:
  MbrType();
  MbrType(int *);
  MbrType(MbrType const &);
  MbrType & operator=(MbrType const &);
};
```

Then, the constructor as you've written it would result in the members having the values that you expect, but a non optimizing compiler would be allowed to implement your constructor as:

```
MemoryManager()
: firstPair_ ()  // implicit call to default constructor
, currentPair_ () // implicit call to default constructor
, lastPair_(currentPair_.operator=(firstPair_.operator=(MbrType (nullptr))))
{/*e.b.*/}
```

Resulting in 6 calls rather than 3.

Comment: @Richard Thank you for your answer. My example has pointers and for those I believe wont result in call to any operator=() for any class they're declared. The whole point is to set in as tearse as possible way those pointers to null. That's all. We not talking here about classes, POD's or anything like this. Just pointers, and for those I believe construction in form (a = b = x) is the most optimal

Comment: @There...: Before claiming that this is "optimal", I would suggest that you see what code is generated for each version of your constructor, most likely they will be identical.  Additionally, if a compiler can deduce that your constructor does nothing but set the pointer values to zero - it may just initialize the entire class with a call to memset - super fast!  Finally, your comment here demonstrates the brittleness of your code, in the future you may want to change these to smart pointers - and now you'll have to modify the constructor too.

Comment: @Richard when I've said is optimal I meant optimal in a sense of how many chars you have to type in order to achieve identical result to "traditional way". Not the code generated. Generated code should be identical and that's the whole point - with far less work you get the same code.

Comment: @Richard to your second part - this about smart pointers - nope, everything stays as it was, no change needed.

Comment: @There...: Number of characters is just not a valid metric to use.  The result is not the "same code", your version is cryptic and brittle.

Comment: @There...:  I'm not suggesting you need to change them to smart pointers now.  I'm highlighting that as your project moves forward - someone may decide to modify the code to use smart pointers.  At which time they should also consider modifying the constructor.

Comment: @Richard but in the case you describe, wouldn't they have to modify ctor anyway? Or let's put it this way: If they change they class design so dramatically that "my construct" just won't do, is there any chance that "the traditional way" will do without any changes?

Comment: @There...: If they've used the "usual" style of initializing all members as follows "firstPair_(nullptr)", then they would not need to change their constructor if they decide to move to smart pointers.

Comment: @Richard but if they decide to move to smart pointers they wouldn't need to change their ctor with my construction either - so I don't really see what's the problem. Unless I see a convincing example (pointers involved)I'm affraid that I'm not going to agree with you.

Answer (score -1):

**No**, but it doesn't matter. Your code does not depend on the order in which `currentPair_` and `firstPair_` are zeroed.

Comment: @MSalters well, that's just an example to visualize what I wanted to ask for. But returning to your answer, you're saying that it won't be evaluated in this order: firstP_ = nullptr, currentP_ = firstP_ and lastP_(currentP_)? Is that how I shall understand your No answer?

Comment: It's an answer to "does it have a well-defined Evaluation Order?". No, it doesn't, it's unspecified. However, all possible orders have the same result. Therefore in this case the EO doesn't matter. Of course, in the most generalized case, the EO does matter. Therefore I can't rule on other examples without seeing them.

Comment: I may be wrong, but both assignment and initialization occurs in a specific order. If it didn't (particularly initialization), I don't think one can expect reliable results from the construct (e.g if the compiler decides to initialize uninitialized members to some magic value).

Comment: initialization occurs in a well-defined order (the order in which the members are declared, as long as they're defined inside the same access block)

Comment: @Jalf:  For this example, no default initialization takes place at all (they're all PODs) so the member order is irrelevant.  As for the requirement that they're in the same access block, can you provide a standard reference?  The access block does affect the memory layout, but AFAIK not the init order.

Comment: @jalf: is your comment a response to my answer? Because my answer concerned the two assignments inside the expression used to initialize `lastPair_`.